# RSpec testing method called on instance variable not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a method in my controller, unreserve, that calls the `find_ticket` method and, if the ticket is found, calls `unreserve` on the ticket.

```
  def unreserve
    if find_ticket
      @ticket.unreserve current_or_guest_user
      render json: @ticket.show.tickets_as_json(current_or_guest_user)
    else
      render json: nil
    end
  end

  private

  def find_ticket
    @ticket = Ticket.find params[:id]
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      false
  else
    true
  end
```

Since I have already tested `unreserve`, I just want to make sure that method is called. So when I try running this spec:

```
describe 'unreserving a ticket' do
  before :each do
    sign_in customer
    put :reserve, id: ticket_1.id
    put :unreserve, id: ticket_1.id
  end
  it 'calls unreserve on the ticket with the current user' do
    expect(controller.instance_variable_get :@ticket).to receive(:unreserve)
  end
end
```

Which I would expect to pass, I even threw a `puts` statement inside the `unreserve` method to make sure that method was being called, and it outputted to the console when I was running the test.

The output I get from the test is:

```
1) TicketsController unreserving a ticket calls unreserve on the ticket with the current user
     Failure/Error: expect(controller.instance_variable_get :@ticket).to receive(:unreserve)
       (#<Ticket:0x007f90dd6c9600>).unreserve(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
```

EDIT:

I tried calling the expect statement before the actions, but still got the same error. Here is the new test:

```
it 'calls unreserve on the ticket with the current user' do
    expect(controller.instance_variable_get :@ticket).to receive(:unreserve)
    sign_in customer
    put :reserve, id: ticket_1.id
    put :unreserve, id: ticket_1.id
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm remembering incorrectly you need to make your expectations before you make your request.  Meaning you can't use a before block (well not entirely).  Move your `put :unreserve` down after your `expect` call like so:

```
describe 'unreserving a ticket' do
  before :each do
    sign_in customer
    put :reserve, id: ticket_1.id
  end
  it 'calls unreserve on the ticket with the current user' do
    expect(controller.instance_variable_get :@ticket).to receive(:unreserve)
    put :unreserve, id: ticket_1.id
  end
end
```

Comment: Grrr, you're right. What a rookie mistake. I changed it up and am still getting the same error though - I edited the post with the new test.

Comment: Are you sure that `find_ticket` is returning true?

Comment: Yes, I checked it and it is working fine. Everything works when I run the app. The problem seems to be that reserving the ticket assigns `@ticket`, and then unreserving it seems to assign `@ticket` to another object. That is my guess at least.

Comment: I just noticed that in your example you call `expect` and then the `put` calls.  Move the expect so that it is just before the final put.